# Symfony2 FOSRestBundle: Demands an Array But Cannot Parse it in config.yml

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, fosrestbundle

I'm using the friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.0.*@dev" bundle, trying to upgrade from Symfony 2.2 to Symfony 2.3. In my app/config/config.yml file, I'm trying to specify rules for the fos_rest format_listener:

```
fos_rest:
    view:
        formats:
            rss: false
            xml: true
            json: true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
            json: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig
    format_listener:
        rules:
                fallback_format: json
                prefer_extension: true
```

When I do this and I run `composer.phar install`, it says

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException]
  Invalid type for path "fos_rest.format_listener.rules.fallback_format". Expected array, but got string
```

When I changed this to an array like so:

```
fallback_format: 
    - json
```

It says

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
  Unrecognized options "0" under "fos_rest.format_listener.rules.fallback_format"
```

I've also tried putting quotes around 'json' but it still says the same thing. A similar error happens when I try setting adding this line to the format_listener rules:

```
default_priorities: ['json', 'html', 'txt', */*]
```

But instead, it says `Unrecognized options "0, 1, 2, 3" under "fos_rest.format_listener.rules.default_priorities"` since there are four values being specified instead of just one.

It seems this bundle is insisting it's supposed to get an array, but then when it's given one, it can't read it.

Has anyone encountered this problem/is this a bug/is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to set json as your default format for requests.  If that is the case, it is done a bit differently now.

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener: true
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
```

EDIT:

If you are wanting to force specific formats, then do something like this:

```
format_listener:
    rules:
        - { path: ^/rest/path, priorities: [html, json, xml], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true}
```

Here's a useful config that I found that is using the FOSRestBundle.  It has similar examples to what I mentioned.  [Example Config](https://github.com/liip-forks/symfony-standard/blob/techtalk/app/config/config.yml)

Comment: Thanks. What about the default_priorities and prefer_extension lines? Also, is this documented somewhere? I was following [the full default configuration](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration-reference.md) when putting that configuration together.

Comment: see my edit.  There are some examples on github from other providers, but I haven't found any solid docs on this yet.

Comment: Ok, here's the official config example:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration-reference.md
This is overdated crap?